# How to highlight a text while reading (SpeechSynthesizer) a specific word in Textbox/RichtextBox?

Tags: c#

SpeechSynthesizer reader = new SpeechSynthesizer();

reader.SpeakAsync(richTextBox1.SelectedText);

// highlight a text while reading (SpeechSynthesizer) a specific word in richTextBox1.

Answer (score 0):

The [SpeechSynthesizer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer(v=vs.110).aspx) raises different Events while progressing.

The one for words is [SpeechSynthesizer.SpeakProgress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.speakprogress(v=vs.110).aspx). Hook up an eventlistener and Color the text in your TextBox inside of that.

Answer (score 0):

You should use SpeakProgress event which raises for each new word was pronounced

> The SpeechSynthesizer raises this event for each new word that it
>   speaks in a prompt using any of the Speak, SpeakAsync, SpeakSsml, or
>   SpeakSsmlAsync methods. For an example and more information about data
>   associated with the event, see SpeakProgressEventArgs.
>    [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.speakprogress(v=vs.110).aspx)

There is also a good example from Microsoft hot to use this event to check what text pronounced:[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speakprogresseventargs(v=vs.110).aspx)